# The flagging dialog should not put all the custom close reasons under the heading of "needs improvement"

Tags: bug, flags, flag-dialog

Reality is that lots of irredeemable questions get asked. There are lots of questions which can't be improved in order for them to become acceptable. The flag dialog should not have been changed to put everything under the heading of "needs improvement" when that is not true for many close reasons.

Please change it to something else. Perhaps "needs to be closed".

For example: in what way should this question be improved?

[image: screenshot of a terrible off-topic MSE question and the flag dialog]

Comment: It used to be called "should be closed ...", which (for the close voters) made perfect sense. Maybe it wasn't friendly/welcoming enough?

Comment: [Machavity's proposal is really solid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346483/256282) - that's what I'd recommend now