# Why are the "off-topic" flag options (including "blatantly off-topic") listed under "needs improvement"?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, off-topic, flag-dialog

When I see an off-topic question on a site where I have the "cast close votes" privilege (mainly, SO), I can click on <kbd>Close</kbd>, select "A community-specific reason" (AKA/previously, "off-topic"), and then select the appropriate option.

Now, on sites where I do *not* have that privilege (<s>like here on Meta SE</s>), I click on <kbd>Flag</kbd> but I initially couldn't find those options and was just about to post a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question asking "how to *flag* off-topic questions" until I realized that the options *do exist*. However, they're buried under the "needs improvement" option, which doesn't make any sense.

If the question is [blatantly] off-topic, why would one select "needs improvement" and expect to find the "off-topic" reasons there? Isn't that counterintuitive?<sup>(1)</sup>

**Can we have the "community-specific reason" moved out of the "needs improvement" sub-list?**<sup>(2)</sup>

---

<sup>(1)</sup> <sub>I guess part of the reason you had to put that option in a sub-list is the fact that the "off-topic" option was renamed to "community-specific reason" (you can flag something as off-topic but you can't "flag it *as community-specific reason!*").</sub>

<sup>(2)</sup> <sub>..and maybe rename it to something like "off-topic for a community-specific reason" or whatever makes sense.</sub>

Comment: Related: [Question close updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346638/) ([this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346654/) in particular), and [Flag window redux proposed syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346483/).

Comment: One remark: the word "off-topic" has a slightly different meaning on SE than elsewhere. The ordinary meaning is "not relevant to the subject under discussion" ( from: https://www.lexico.com/definition/off-topic ), but on SE it means "not allowed to be asked about on this site" and the first definition need not apply. (consider programming questions on [cs.se]. Programming is certainly _relevant_ to the discussion of computer science, but it is still "off-topic" because we have decided such question should be asked on [so].)

Comment: @Discretelizard True! Maybe something like "out of scope" then? I don't really have a solid suggestion (and English isn't my first language too) but I know that those options definitely shouldn't be under "needs improvement".

Comment: I think replacing "community specific reason" by "should be closed" as suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346483/) works well. (although it works better in the context of a redesigned menu as suggested in the post) Alternatively, you can use "not on topic according to the help center" (with a link). This uses the special meaning SE has for the term, but also explains it.