# Make the abuse flag descriptions include system abuse (ex. gibberish), and link to the abuse flag FAQ post

Tags: feature-request, flag-dialog

**Proposal:** Make the abuse flag descriptions include system abuse (ex. gibberish), and link to [the spam/abuse flag FAQ post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/997587).

This would be for both the post flags (rude/abusive), and comment flags (harassment/bigotry/abuse).

In the FAQ post on spam/abuse flagging, it says:

> *Abuse of the system* or *community* is everything that is created with the intention to harm them. [This includes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/997587) posts [by new users](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26705146#26705146) that contain no useful content at all – i.e. gibberish posts along the lines of:
>
> > asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd

Currently, on Stack Overflow (just for the sake of an example with actual links), the comment flag description says:

> It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.
> This comment attacks a person or group. Learn more in our [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#personal-attacks).

and the post flag description says:

> rude or abusive
> A reasonable person would find this content [inappropriate for respectful discourse](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct).

I think this is important, since I personally find the FAQ posts to not be very discoverable. When I started actively contributing, I didn't know they existed until I really went looking for them. It would be a shame if many people didn't flag things that should be flagged just because they didn't know certain things qualified to be flagged for existing flag reasons.

Comment: Related (in that the updated messaging for the R/A flag in this request includes what you would want): [Flag window redux: proposed syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346483/622284)

Comment: @Spevacus I didn't know about that one! I wouldn't be very opposed to my post here getting marked as a duplicate. But I also think there's value in my request's very small scope (less work -> more likely to happen?) oh wait- that one is already [tag:status-review]...

Comment: @starball [status-review] doesn't mean that the request will get implemented. It's often not even added by staff, but by moderators. When mods add a [status-review] tag to a question, it creates an internal ticket for the staff. That's about it. I would say this question is not a duplicate of the linked one (which is likely why Spevacus indicated that it just "related").

Comment: Indeed. The tag wiki for it's a bit out of date, but here's the post describing the relevant process: [What posts should be escalated to staff using \[status-review\], and how do I escalate them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/335251)

Comment: FWIW, [the help center for "flag posts" privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) already links there (but who reads the help center anyway...).

Comment: @V2Blast I [tried to update the wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/84115) [and excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/84116) a while ago, but was rejected.

Comment: I am concerned about what text would be used in the flagging dialogs for this proposed change. When it's appropriate to use R/A flags for things that are "abuse of the system" is *notably* more complex than just "flag everything" that looks like the user is abusing the system. It's *specifically* only to be used for *new users* who don't have other contributions, and *only* for things which are *complete* gibberish, without other redeeming content. While that could be communicated in the flagging dialog, it's quite a bit more nuanced than what's generally described there.