# Make the opinion-based closure notice say "is seeking opinion-based answers" instead of "is opinion-based"

Tags: bug, close-reasons, wording, post-notices

When a question is closed as:

> **Opinion-based**
> This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

…a post notice is placed above the question, for example:

[image: Post notice for a question closed as “opinion based”.]

This says:

> **Closed**. This question is [opinion-based](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). It is not currently accepting answers.

But the problem is not that the *question* is opinion based, the real problem is that question is soliciting opinion-based *answers*.

---

I suggest that the post notice wording be changed to something such as:

> **Closed**. This question is seeking [opinion-based](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) answers. It is not currently accepting answers.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388030/997587. not sure what its status is.

Comment: @starball "I'd always thought the proper path for closed questions was to edit and fix and then reopen." The system allows you to abandon your previous question asking attempt and ask another one. One could say there are different paths to fixing questions. What was problematic in the past was that even fixed questions, as rarely as that happened, didn't get reopened or didn't make it to a positive score unless one acted really fast. I don't know what the best/proper path is. Maybe the staging ground would have helped.

Comment: Are these question actively seeking opinionated answers? More like they attract them because some sort of specification is missing, like asking for what is the best without specifying what best should mean. Maybe all these questions are secretly underspecified?